# SQL Server Management Studio crashes after opening database diagram

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have 2 existing database diagram in local server in SQL Server 2018, SSMS 18.1
While opening it, the application becomes "Not Responding" then crashes without any error. It was working fine for the last 7 days.

Comment: Did you check the Event Viewer for any errors?

Comment: Is Application crashing issues relevant to this forum? An application can crash for so many reasons, which is difficult to define and more difficult to provide solution.

Comment: SQL Server 2018, I've seen this version mentioned multiple times in the last few days. Can someone point me to the official docs?

Comment: Did you find any answer?

Comment: Somewhat. But, I forgot exactly what I did. Someone said to delete something from SSMS. It deleted my user-credentials too. Luckily I had 2 user credentials

Comment: @Gibrán check the answer mentioned by Mehran & check comments. It's not the exact answer & it deletes server credential but, I had my schema's credential. So, it worked. Shouldn't try in production

Comment: I have discovered a workaround and posted it here: [https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/37992649-ssms-18-1-crashes-when-opening-a-database-diagram](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/37992649-ssms-18-1-crashes-when-opening-a-database-diagram) Short answer, use REG hack to turn of telemetry...

Comment: read this answers https://stackoverflow.com/a/63085851/11258674

Answer (score 3):

By mean 18, if you have SSMS version 18.0 installed then Database Diagrams were deprecated and removed from 18.0 version, and added back into SSMS version 18.1.

[Source: Deprecated and removed features in 18.0:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/release-notes-ssms?view=sql-server-2017#deprecated-features)

check out Deprecated and removed features in 18.0 in above Release notes for SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS).

Comment: sorry, it is 18.1

Comment: try deleting "SQL Server Management Studio" folder from My Documents, It results all settings gone along with any crashes. i repeat you will lose all current settings if any. Hope this works otherwise Uninstall / reinstall.

Comment: oh.it even removed password everything

Comment: Deleting that folder did not fix the crash for me.

Answer (score 1):

I have been dealing with the same issue on SSMS 18.5.

I do not know what causes the [dbo].[sysdiagrams] table to become corrupted but I have found that if I copy the diagrams from an older (working) version of the database, they are editable again.

The TSQL I used to solve the problem:

```
DELETE FROM [corrupt_database].[dbo].[sysdiagrams];

INSERT INTO [corrupt_database].[dbo].[sysdiagrams]
SELECT [name],
       [principal_id],
       [version],
       [definition]
FROM [valid_database].[dbo].[sysdiagrams];
```

From my initial testing, the diagrams will save and reopen again; even after restarting SSMS.

Comment: For those not reading closely as I was not, this is not valid in SQL Database (Azure).

Answer (score 0):

As a temporary fix use older versions of [SSMS (17.9)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/release-notes-ssms?view=sql-server-2017#1791), This will limt your feature set.

Microsoft has posted a article about the bug [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035/suggestions/37992649)

Answer (score 0):

SSMS Database Diagrams currently work correctly in 17.9.1 and 18.6.

Note: though this issue was fixed in SSMS 18.6, it has returned again in 18.7.X.